# ImportError: cannot import name _unquotepath

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy for my project & after some initial struggle i started with https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

When i use :

`scrapy startproject tutorial`

It throws me error:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-241-62-56:~/Selenim$ scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.url import escape_ajax
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/url.py", line 15, in <module>
    from w3lib.url import _safe_chars, _unquotepath
ImportError: cannot import name _unquotepath
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: I don't know scrapy or w3lib.url, so I don't have a ready made answer for you, but an observation that might help. Since both imported idenfiers start with _, they're both supposed to be private inside w3lib.url and not part of the API. This is often done to prevent importers of a module becoming dependent on design decisions that might change. It seems that scrapy ignores that convention.

Comment: @Kittystone, can you paste (in your answer) the ouput of `scrapy version -v`? `from w3lib.url import _safe_chars, _unquotepath` is part of the move of `canonicalize_url` to `w3lib.url`. And needs `w3lib`>=1.15. Try `pip install --upgrade w3lib`. (Scrapy itself does not use `_unquotepath`, but importers of `scrapy.utils.url` may rely on it, that's why it was left available.)

Comment: For more info on why import of `_unquotepath` was left, see the discussion in https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2168

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading w3lib (to 1.15.0) solved the problem for me.